# tablesorter pager.js is not working

Tags: 8

I have successfully added the tablesorter.js library to a table in my drupal website but when I try to add the pager, the input and select Html that I add do not show up.  I add this HTML

```
    <div id="pager" class="pager">
    <form>
        <img src="../addons/pager/icons/first.png" class="first"/>
        <img src="../addons/pager/icons/prev.png" class="prev"/>
        <input type="text" class="pagedisplay"/>
        <img src="../addons/pager/icons/next.png" class="next"/>
        <img src="../addons/pager/icons/last.png" class="last"/>
        <select class="pagesize">
            <option selected="selected"  value="10">10</option>
            <option value="20">20</option>
            <option value="30">30</option>
            <option  value="40">40</option>
        </select>
    </form>
</div>
```

but something in the drupal site makes the select options and the input options disappear from the final page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to add the form and form elements as a Form under the src/ directory and call it with

```
 $form= \Drupal::formBuilder()->getForm('Drupal\pup_viewfiles\Form\PagerForm', $extra);
```